# MSSQL CASE after ORDER BY not working with alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-server-2014, alias

Hello Stack Overflow Community!

I'm sitting here with my colleague and we're trying to solve a problem we currently have with MSSQL 2014.

We have a table with a number of columns, where two of them are containing a Date. 
Just for comprehension; one date ('Liefertermin') shows when/if it actually was delivered and the other one ('FreiesDatum1') shows when it is planned to be delivered.

If 'Liefertermin' is not empty then it should show up and otherwise 'FreiesDatum1' should appear.
We solved this with the following query which works as it should:

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN Liefertermin is null THEN cast(FreiesDatum1 as date)
       ELSE Liefertermin
    END as SortDate
FROM Beleg
```

There are of course some other columns in the SELECT-query, but those aren't necessary for the problem. We wanted to have the sorting dynamic, so we could choose between different types. For that we declared a variable (@Sort) at the beginning and set up a CASE-Statement after the 'order by'.

And now there's the problem we're facing:

We are unable to order by the 'SortDate', that is selected above, if it stands in the CASE-statement. If we just do `order by 'SortDate'` it works without any problem.

This is our attempt, that does not work:

```
order by CASE
            when @Sort=1 then 'SortDate'
            when @Sort=2 then 'Liefertermin'
            when @Sort=3 then 'Name'
          END
```

@Sort=1 doesn't, but @Sort=2 and @Sort=3 do work so I guess there's no Problem with the CASE itself. When removing the marks I get an error, that the column 'SortDate' does not exist.

We already tried changing the alias to [SortDate] or 'SortDate' without any success and also tried using a derived table but we got the same result.

We searched through these forums here and tried every solution that worked for other problems with CASE-statements, but none of these worked.

Really hope for help here!
Greetings
3m7ecc

EDIT:

Here is the full SQL-Query

```
Declare @Sort integer;
Set @Sort = 1

select
    Beleg.Belegnummer,
    Beleg.Belegtyp,
    Beleg.Datum,
    wp.Projekt,
    wp.Bezeichnung as 'Projektbezeichnung',
    BELEG.Adressnummer,
    BELEG.Firma,
    BELEG.Ort,
    convert(varchar(10),BELEG.Liefertermin,104) as Liefertermin,
    convert(varchar(10),BELEG.FreiesDatum1,104) as iLiefertermin,
    Beleg.Netto,
    BELEG.Status,
    cast(BELEG.Datum as date) as Erfassungsdatum,
    CASE
        when BELEG.Liefertermin is null then Beleg.FreiesDatum1
        else BELEG.Liefertermin
    END as SortDate
from BELEG
left join WPROJEKT as WP on (wp.Id = BELEG.Projekt)
    where 
    (('01.09.2017' is null or convert(varchar(10),BELEG.Liefertermin,104) >= '01.09.2017')
        and ('31.10.2017' is null or convert(varchar(10),BELEG.Liefertermin,104) <= '31.10.2017')) 
    and Beleg.belegtyp = 'B'
    and ((BELEG.Liefertermin is null
    and BELEG.FreiesDatum1 is null)
    or (BELEG.Liefertermin <= GETDATE() or BELEG.FreiesDatum1 <= GETDATE()))

ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 then SortDate END DESC,
CASE WHEN @Sort = 2 then Liefertermin END DESC,
CASE WHEN @Sort = 3 then BELEG.Belegnummer END DESC
```

Comment: I don't think that order by 'SortDate' works properly. I would recommend you to white columns names without single quotes, use something like [SortDate] or [Liefertermin];

Comment: You are sorting by a constant, in each case: `'SortDate'` is a string, not a reference to the `SortDate` column. I think you want to remove the `'`

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick help, but as I stated, when I remove the marks I got the error, that the Column doesn't exist!

Comment: Can you use the ordinal number of the column in the query, eg ORDER BY 7?

Comment: @No'amNewman Yes, I can use it but it won't sort it..

Comment: Because you have another case statement which you are aliasing as that column. Try `CASE WHEN @Sort=1 then FreiesDatum1`

Comment: But that way it would sort the list by the Column 'FreiesDatum1' which it shouldn't. In SortDate there's a Date for every row, since FreiesDatum1 and Liefertermin are kind of merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use aliased columns in the ORDER BY clause because sorting logically it happens before the SELECT clause. You could use column numbers, e.g. ORDER BY 9 would sort the output by your 'Liefertermin' column, but that is considered a bad practice. Best way around it would be to put everything inside a subquery, like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT... -- your whole select here without the ORDER BY clause
 ) as t1
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 then SortDate END DESC
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 2 then Liefertermin END DESC
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 3 then Name END DESC
```

Comment: I already tried with the numbers, that didn't work out, but the subquery one seemed to have worked!
The only weird thing is, that I tried it before but it didn't work..
Maybe I forgot something when I tried before.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

You need to wrap your current select statement in a parent SELECT * FROM, then add the order by statement at the end as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        Beleg.Belegnummer,
        Beleg.Belegtyp,
        Beleg.Datum,
        wp.Projekt,
        wp.Bezeichnung as 'Projektbezeichnung',
        BELEG.Adressnummer,
        BELEG.Firma,
        BELEG.Ort,
        convert(varchar(10),BELEG.Liefertermin,104) as Liefertermin,
        convert(varchar(10),BELEG.FreiesDatum1,104) as iLiefertermin,
        Beleg.Netto,
        BELEG.Status,
        cast(BELEG.Datum as date) as Erfassungsdatum,
        CASE
            when BELEG.Liefertermin is null then Beleg.FreiesDatum1
            else BELEG.Liefertermin
        END as SortDate
    FROM BELEG
    LEFT JOIN WPROJEKT as WP on (wp.Id = BELEG.Projekt)
        where 
        (('01.09.2017' is null or convert(varchar(10),BELEG.Liefertermin,104) >= '01.09.2017')
            and ('31.10.2017' is null or convert(varchar(10),BELEG.Liefertermin,104) <= '31.10.2017')) 
        and Beleg.belegtyp = 'B'
        and ((BELEG.Liefertermin is null
        and BELEG.FreiesDatum1 is null)
        or (BELEG.Liefertermin <= GETDATE() or BELEG.FreiesDatum1 <= GETDATE()))
) AS NewBeleg

ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 then NewBeleg.SortDate END DESC
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 2 then NewBeleg.Liefertermin END DESC
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 3 then NewBeleg.Name END DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this isn't working either..
It throws the error, that 'SortDate' is an invalid column name!
And if  I put  marks around the SortDate  like  'SortDate' within the CASE it just doesn't do anything. There's no error but it isn't sorting either.

Comment: Can you post the whole SQL statement with the order by that you tried? When adding the marks around 'SortDate', it will sort by the string 'SortDate' that's why it works with the marks

Comment: This should work.  Do you note that there are three different `case` expressions.

Comment: Can you try: BELEG.SortDate? Add it in the order by. Do you have another SortDate field in the WPROJEKT table? (updated the order by code above)

Comment: This also doesn't work, since SortDate isn't part of the BELEG table. I get the same error with unknown column.

Comment: Ok found the issue, you need to wrap your select statement in a parent SELECT * FROM statement so that SortDate would be part of your new table.. check updated answer

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I think PacoDePaco posted the solution just before you did

Answer (score 0):

You can give column number instead of column name in order by clause
like

```
order by
CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 then 2 END DESC
```

where 2 is the column number of Sortdate.

Otherwise, don't use the alias name use the [tablename].[columname] instead.

or You can use

```
select * from (

your query
...
) as T1

order by 
case WHEN @Sort = 1 then T1.[Sortdate] END DESC,
```

....

Answer (score 0):

You could use CTE and avoid declaring variables, much more clean approach!

```
with your_cte as (
  select isnull(Liefertermin, FreiesDatum1) as SortDate
  from beleg
)

select * from your_cte order by SortDate
```

[CTE Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

For a reason that I can't fathom yet, you don't seem to ba able to use a column alias in an `ORDER BY` that uses a `CASE`.
You'll have to re-enter the original case statement and next it in the ORDER BY CASE e.g.

```
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 then (CASE
                                when BELEG.Liefertermin is null then Beleg.FreiesDatum1
                                else BELEG.Liefertermin
                              END) END DESC
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 2 then NewBeleg.Liefertermin END DESC
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 3 then NewBeleg.Name END DESC
```

Since @Sort can only equal one value though you need only have 1 case e.g.

```
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @Sort = 1 then (CASE
                                when BELEG.Liefertermin is null then Beleg.FreiesDatum1
                                else BELEG.Liefertermin
                              END) DESC
         WHEN @Sort = 2 then NewBeleg.Liefertermin DESC
         WHEN @Sort = 3 then NewBeleg.Name DESC
```